# AppManfiest.xml vs WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can any one explain me the difference between AppManifets(to my understanding it is .net package info) and WMAppManifest(to my understanding information about the app) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppManifest.xml describes the deployment of your app (libraries and such).

This page describes it better than I can.

[What is AppManifest.xaml in Silverlight?](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/05/what-is-appmanifestxaml-in-silverlight.html)

---

WMAppManifest.xaml describes the

Application UI

- Change your display name, and icons here.

Capabilites

- Change what permission you want to ask the user to allow your app to do.

Requirements

- Set a specific settings that the phone must meet, like having a front camera.

Packaging

- Set various settings for submitting to the App store.